# Cannot use Content.ReadAsAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms, httprequest

My Login.xaml.cs calls this class:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel(string entryValue) {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var clientIDValue = entryValue;
        LoginModel loginModelCientID = new LoginModel();
        loginModelCientID.clientID = clientIDValue;

        var entryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModelCientID);
        var content = new StringContent(entryJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Console.WriteLine(entryJson);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = "http://******/test.php";
            var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            var resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

However, I get an error saying:

> Task does not contain a definition for content
>   and no accessible...

I'm trying to make a post request and store the output to a variable.

I am very new to C#, let alone xamarin forms. An additional question would be, what does ReadAsStringAsync() actually store?

Example I have a PHP code saying

```
if ($test == null) {
 echo "not ok";
} else {
 echo "ok";
}
```

Does it store the output of the echo command?

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the event handler async and then await functions that return Task derived results as you would have ended up with the same problem when calling `ReadAsStringAsync`

change

```
var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content);
var resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

to

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entryJson);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(uri, byteContent);
```

instead of:

```
var content = new StringContent(entryJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

`ReadAsStringAsync()` Converts the json/xml response of your web api to string.

After reading it as string, Deserialize it if needed.